# optional regex match?

Tags: regex, perl

How can I match an optional character in a regex expression?

I am trying to write a small file that does a little housekeeping to our NAS.

The script goes through the folders inside the specified root folder.

For my testing the root is `C:\Users\Solignis\Desktop\Orders`

This is where I have the first match take place, it checks to be sure the file matches our standard name convention which is the city + 3 digit folder + 3 digit file number.

Sometimes though we have extra files that have a `_1 or _2` on them to denote an additional page.

How can I make this regex expression also fit the "optional" `_1 or _2 and sometimes _3` into the match?

The code:

```
$file =~ /^ ((C[A|F|L]|ME)) (\d{3}) (\d{3}) \. (PDF) /xmi
```

I am sure this is easy bit I still got loops on the brain from having to "drill" into this giant hash of arrays I made which is something like 25k files in some of the arrays.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Does `[A|F|L]` work for you? `[AFL]` is correct one, IMHO, and also double brackets `((....))` to `(C[AFL]|ME)` would be better

Comment: That does that same thing? If so works for me, cuz it works with the alternates between each letter too. But your way is less cluttered.

Comment: @Solignis, not same, I think your regex will match the file named `"C|111222.PDF"`. and double brackets will make your $1 and $2 is same. But just changing `((...))` to `(...)` would break your code, you need to update the code that used $3, $4, $5, IMHO.

Comment: the `|` do nothing except cause `C|` to be a valid match

Comment: I see, well the only valid matches "should" be `CA, CF, CL and ME` nothing else.

Comment: By the way why you use this: `(PDF)` in your regex?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something like `(_[1-3])?`

`?` Matches zero or one instance.

might be what you are looking for.

Comment: could that be expanded to match `_\d*`?

Comment: Awesome it works!, I "fused" it into the part of the expression that looks for the file number. Works perfect, thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 5):

Something like `(?: _[1-3] )?` if don't want to catch this group.